# Conditional types declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm not sure if I can do this, but I was wondering if based on the value of a key of my interface (which type is an enum), I can conditionally select what type another key of the same interface is going to be. I don't think you are going to understand without an example so, here we go.

I have some types declaration that looks basically like this:

```
interface BookingTextInput {
  type: InputType.text;
  metadata: TextInputMetadata;
}

interface BookingSelectInput {
  type: InputType.selectGrid;
  metadata: SelectInputMetadata;
}

interface BookingNumberInput {
  type: InputType.number;
  metadata: NumberInputMetadata;
}

type BookingInput = BookingTextInput | BookingNumberInput | BookingSelectInput;
```

And what I want to do is to avoid having to do an interface for each `InputType` enum value and instead do a `BookingInput` interface that conditionally see what value is in the type key and based on that, it knows what type is the metadata key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a interface to map from enum type to the metadata interface and then use a mapped type to get a union that is functionally equivalent to what you have now:

```
interface InputTypeToInterfaceMap {
  [InputType.text]: TextInputMetadata;
  [InputType.selectGrid]: TextInputMetadata;
  [InputType.number]: TextInputMetadata;
}

type BookingInput = { 
    [P in keyof InputTypeToInterfaceMap]: {
        type: P; metadata: InputTypeToInterfaceMap[P] 
    } 
}[keyof InputTypeToInterfaceMap];
```

This makes the code a lot more terse and you only have to modify the `enum` and the mapping interface to add a new type.

A shorter way would be to not use an enum at all. I find the need for enums greatly reduced since string literal types were added. Using the interface map with simple enums and using `keyof` to extract the union of keys can achieve the same type safety goals with less changes when you want to add a new type:

```
interface InputTypeToInterfaceMap {
    text: TextInputMetadata;
    selectGrid: TextInputMetadata;
    number: TextInputMetadata;
}

type InputType = keyof InputTypeToInterfaceMap //  "number" | "text" | "selectGrid"
type BookingInput = {
    [P in keyof InputTypeToInterfaceMap]: {
        type: P; metadata: InputTypeToInterfaceMap[P]
    }
}[keyof InputTypeToInterfaceMap];
```

Comment: It worked great and was really what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#type-guard). Here's a little example how it works:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;

function isString(x: Primitive): x is string {
    return typeof x === "string";
}

function isNumber(x: Primitive): x is number {
    return typeof x === "number";
}

function isBoolean(x: Primitive): x is boolean {
    return typeof x === "boolean";
}

let str: Primitive = "text";
let nmb: Primitive = 1;
let bln: Primitive = true;

let prms = [str, nmb, bln];

for (let x of prms) {
    if (isString(x)) {
        console.log(`string value: ${x}`);
    } else if (isNumber(x)) {
        console.log(`number value: ${x}`);
    } else if (isBoolean) {
        console.log(`boolean value: ${x}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`unknown type value: ${x}`);
    }
}
```

But for complex types I'd recommend to use Union Types as in your example.